# Custom Video File how much would I extract the images?

Tags: directx, video

I alot of people would recommend that why not go with Bink or use DirectShow in order to play a video or even ffmpeg. However, what are movies anyways - just images put all together with sound.

I've already created a program where I take a bunch of images and place them into the customize video file. The cool thing about this - is that I can easily place it on a quad. The issue I'm having is I can only extract one image from the custom video file. When I have more than one; I have problems, which I fully understand.

I have a index lookup table of all the images sizes then the raw images. The calculation I was following was:

```
 offset = NumberOfImages + 1 * sizeof(long).
```

So, with the one image - if you'll perform the offset of finding the first image would be quite easy. During the for loop it always starts with 0 and and reaches the number of images which is 1. So, it would translate like this:

```
  offset = 1 + 1 * 4 = 8.
```

So, now I know the offset just for one image which is great. However, a video is with a bunch of images all together. So, I've been thinking to myself...If there was a way to reach up to a certain point then stuff the read data inside a vector.

```
    currentPosition = 0; //-- Set the current position to zero before looping through images in file.

     for (UINT i = 0; i < elements; i++) {

         long tblSz = (elements + 1) * sizeof(long); // elements + 1 * 4

         long off =  tblSz + currentPosition; // -- Now let's calculate the offset position inside the file knowing the table size.
        // in.seekg(off, std::ios_base::end); //-- Not used.
         long videoSz = sicVideoIndexTable[i]; //-- Let's retreive the image size from the index table that's stored inside the file before we process each image.
        // in.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg); //-- Not used.
             dataBuf.resize(videoSz); //-- Let's resize the data Buffer vector to fit the image size.
         in.seekg(off, std::ios_base::beg); //-- Let's go to the calculated offset position to retrieve the image data.
         std::streamsize currpos = in.gcount(); //-- Prototype not used.
                 in.read(&dataBuf[0], videoSz); //-- Let's read in the data according to the image size.

                     sVideoDesc.dataPtr = (void*)&dataBuf[0]; //-- Pass what we've read into the temporary structor before pushing it inside a vector to store the collection of images.
         sVideoDesc.fileSize = videoSz;
         sicVideoArray.push_back(sVideoDesc);

         dataBuf.empty(); //-- Now can empty the data vector so it can be reused.
         currentPosition = videoSz; //-- Set the current position to the video size so it can recalculate the offset for the next image.
     }
```

I believe the problem lies within the seekg and in.read but that's just my gut telling me that. As you see the current position always changes.

Buttom line question is if I can load one image then why won't I be able to load multiple images from the custom video file? I'm not sure if I'm using seekg or should I just get every character until a certain point them dump the content inside a data buffer vector. I thought reading the block of data would be the answer - but I'm becoming very unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally understand what your code does. You really should use more descriptive variable names. Or at least add an explanation of what each variable means. Anyway...

I believe your problem is in this line:

```
currentPosition = videoSz;
```

When it should be

```
currentPosition += videoSz;
```

You basically don't advance through your file.

Also, if you just read the images in sequentially, you might want to change your file format so that instead of a table of image sizes at the beginning, you store each image size directly followed by the image data. That way you don't need to do any of the offset calculations or seeking.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making things not clear. I am working on good coding ethics more often for the sake of myself and behalf of others. Also, I'm going to give it a try and see how it turns out. I'll let you know how the result is.

Comment: +1 thanks just in case; for debugging purposes I wrote back out individual images just to ensure the file was indeed being read correctly. It worked like a charm.